# Attempting to retrieve data from firebase database with Swift

Tags: iphone, swift

I have a firebase database that contains a location with a name, latitude, and longitude. I want to access all these three values and create a "Cord" object that I need and put it into my array of Cords. At the moment the array stays blank as I print it.

This is the observer for the database

[image]

This is the actual database and the values

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` statement will be running immediately here, before the database has retrieved anything. If you move that line just below the end of your `for` loop you should see it print the result.